Passing `volatile` buffers to library functions which do not take `volatile`
I have a multi-processor system with a "shared" memory region used for communication. In some cases one of the processors needs to process some considerably large data in the shared memory and place the result back.  Normally, I would access the shared memory using volatile pointers to ensure the data is written and read from it, when instructed and the correct data is visible to all the processors (consider it is not cached memory), but unfortunately the processing needs to be done using library functions, while the library isn't written with any special considerations for shared memory (i.e. not taking volatile pointers fore one). Here is an artificial example for illustration:
struct request {
    size_t    data_size;
    uint8_t   data[MAX_REQ];
}

struct response {
    size_t    data_size;
    uint8_t   some_other_data[MAX_RESP];
}

volatile struct request req __attribute__((section(".shared_mem")));
volatile struct request resp __attribute__((section(".shared_mem")));

// The function that is provided by a library I have no control over
extern void library_function(uint8_t* data_in, size_t size_in, uint8_t* data_out, size_t size_out);


// The required usage
library_function(req.data_size, req.data, resp.data_size, req.some_other_data);
...... 

This will obviously and rightfully give a warning similar to
expected 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} but argument is of type 'volatile uint8_t *' {aka 'volatile unsigned char *'}
   20 | extern void library_function(uint8_t* data_in, size_t size_in, uint8_t* data_out, size_t size_out);

and rightfully so.
First of all I am not completely getting the picture of what could go wrong with the code. Since the function is in external library, the compiler has no way of knowing what it does with the passed buffers, so likely won't ever optimize the call out. The optimization on the library side is not a concern I guess. Is LTO the only potential troublemaker here?
Second, if there is indeed a potential issue, but my question is whether there is any way around it (not only the warning, but potential issues of the memory not being properly accessed as expected) besides copying the data back and forth to/from a local buffer before and after processing, and letting the function to work with the local memory instead (disabling optimizations globally isn't a good solution too, besides I am not sure it gives any guarantee).
Note, the question is not about synchronization between the processors or potential race-conditions when both processors might be accessing the same memory at a time of the processing, but purely about what the compiler might do to "screw up" the expected logic.

volatile accesses do not really have anything to do with cache coherency.

@IanAbbott I am not talking about cache at all. I want to make sure that a compiler, when it sees that I write to this buffer, will actually generate an instruction to write to it. Same for reading.

What do you expect the library function to do, if not read from the input buffer and write to the output buffer? Are other processes monitoring the buffers during the call to the library function? What inter-process communication mechanisms do you have available?

So long as you are passing in pointers, the library routines will, by the time they return, have updated memory. So the library routine does not need to be volatile. HOWEVER, be aware that the library routine will not necessarily update memory in a predictable or intuitive way. You can have points in time when your shared memory image will be in an inconsistent state, before the library routine returns. Having the library routine do its work directly in the shared memory is risky if other threads might be accessing that memory concurrently.

@IanAbbott Here is some example: https://godbolt.org/z/fsWEKeYvs As you can see the memory in neither buff nor vbuff is ever read/written, because memset is discarding volatile, and the compiler is assuming it is already set to zero. But memset is a special case as it is a standard function that the compiler might be making special assumptions about it.

gcc does not optimize reads or calls even if object is const. https://godbolt.org/z/7fEfhMaoh

@0___________ The code I have in place (which is ignoring the issue) works as well. The question is whether it might go broken unexpectedly.

@IanAbbott Looks like I might have misinterpreted the x86 assembly, as I am working with a different arch...so this example is not good. Of course it is UB in the sense that the program would behave differently whether the memory might be accessed or might not be, and this is exactly the question, how "badly" it is undefined and what to do to make it more defined.

(Correction to deleted comment) In your example https://godbolt.org/z/fsWEKeYvs it looks like each of the buffers buff and vbuff is overwritten only once. Further examination (by modifying the second argument of the memset call to non-zero value) shows that the calls to foo are being optimized out. Of course this is all UB as far as library access to vbuff is concerned, as is your question's code's call to library_function assuming that function's code accesses the buffers.

TBH, the question should probably be closed as opinion-based once we start arguing about how "badly" the behavior is undefined!

@IanAbbott The questions are stated in the question body and are pretty much closed-ended. Comments are not part of the question an I allow myself here to use less formal language.

Why do you think the problem has to do with linking or optimization at all? The warning is unrelated to those steps, and is telling you that there's a qualifier missing on the type. Put another way, you're providing the wrong type to the function.
In this instance, the compiler is certainly doing the right thing by warning you. When a variable is volatile, this means it could be changed anywhere - we regularly define things as volatile when they could be changed by hardware events completely outside the environment your program is operating in, say by a pin change which triggers an interrupt which writes this variable.
You should ensure that any such variable is always accessed by code which knows it is volatile. The library function you are calling, however does not know this. It will be optimised by assuming the variable is not volatile, and may end up using stale values of the variable. This may not even a result of the  optimization of the library during its building - the library code may itself be written to miminize reads of that variable, or the authors may have subconsciously made design choices under the assumption the variable is not volatile. Volatile is the special case - the dominant assumption is that variables are well defined to the extent that your code can explain everything that happens to that variable.
To avoid the warning and the issue, you should copy the volatile value into a regular variable and use that to call the function. This way, you know with certainty what value the function  used. In case the value changed during the function's execution, you can in principle detect it and take corrective action if your application requires it.

The warning is unrelated to those steps, and is telling you that there's a qualifier missing on the type. - it is very related, because volatile qualified is only relevant for optimization steps. I know all this, and my question is not why this warning is happening or what volatile is, but how I can work around the issue, and what will happen if I forcibly cast/ignore the warning.

Clang and gcc require for correctness that volatile qualifiers be used on objects whose value might be affected by other volatile accesses, but would not be subject to being externally accessed at other times.  Passing such objects to ordinary functions using "ordinary" pointers should be safe when using compilers whose maintainers recognize excessively prioritized optimization as the root of all evil.  Alas, compilers like clang and gcc are maintained by people who prioritize optimization above compatibility with useful programs.

@EugeneSh. If you're certain regular access of your variable is safe, you can always take responsibility for that and explicitly cast it to a non volatile type.  That said, volatile variables are usually volatile for a reason. In this instance, you are opening up to the possibility your variable will change from under you during the functions execution, and depending on the way the library is written and optimised, it might end up using the old value entirely or a chimera of the old and the new.

Re “Why do you think the problem has to do with linking or optimization at all?”: Regarding optimization, the only reason volatile exists is because of optimization. The C standard specifies C semantics using an abstract machine in which each access to an object is a read or a write in the abstract machine. Then the C standard permits C implementations to use any actual implementation of the code provide that certain defined observable behavior is the same for the actual implementation as it is for the abstract machine…

… This license allows optimization: Each access to an object in the code does not have to be an access in the actual implementation. If a C implementation implemented the abstract machine directly, with no optimization, then volatile would have no effect; the C implementation would already be implementing an actual access for each semantic abstract machine access. It is only when optimization is performed that volatile is needed. And that is why the problem has to do with optimization.

Regarding linking, although the C standard permits many things, some of them cannot cross the linking barrier, as a matter of logic and design. When using a C implementation that compiles each translation unit separately and provides only limited information in the object module, and the linker links using that information and does not perform any significant link-time optimization, then we can deduce that certain things that are theoretically permitted by the C standard cannot happen in practice. Among this is the fact that calling an external library obeys the ABI…

… If the library is given a pointer to a buffer and puts data in that buffer, there is no mechanism by which it can cache that data in registers instead of writing it to the buffer. When the routine returns, the data must actually be in the buffer. OP’s question is getting at this effect: In such a C implementation, is it necessarily true that, when the library routine returns, the data will be in memory, even if the library routine did not use volatile? It is a reasonable question, and linking is a crucial part of it.

There is no reason in the question to assume the library is being compiled by the OP, and that any optimization occurring during the library build is within his control. Whatever machine code the library build includes is the code that is going to execute. Optimization occurring during the build of the OPs C files, or any LTO that may happen, amplifies the risk of issues. However, unrelated to optimization, the dangers of passing in a volatile variable to a function not expecting it to be volatile are non zero and significant in the general case.

The function will write to the buffer, yes. However, there is nothing preventing the source of the volatility from also writing to that buffer. Since you do not know the implementation of the library function, there is no reason to assume it will write the whole buffer in one go, and that the resulting state of the buffer is consistent at the time the function returns.

@ChintalagiriShashank Synchronization question is orthogonal. Assume the buffer is untouched on the other size at a time of the function processing, that is there are no race conditions.

@ChintalagiriShashank: Re “However, there is nothing preventing the source of the volatility from also writing to that buffer. Since you do not know the implementation of the library function, there is no reason to assume it will write the whole buffer in one go, and that the resulting state of the buffer is consistent at the time the function returns”: You are considering the entirety of what the C standard permits. That is not what this question is about. It is not about a situation in which some external hardware might write to the buffer at any moment…

@EugeneSh if the buffer remains untouched for that duration, and you know it will be, you can safely cast it to non volatile. The whole point of volatile in my world however, is to indicate that that guarantee cannot be made. If I see such a case in embedded code dealing with hardware registers for example, you can be sure I'm going to spend a lot of time rewriting everything that person touched.

… In this situation (some of it implied and should be clarified in the question), some other process writes data to the buffer, and then this process uses the data and owns it for a period of time. The data will not change from other sources. Then the library routine is called, and it updates the data, and, again, the data is not changed or used by other processes or hardware. Then the library routines, and the data is changed in memory and is consistent. That is what this question is about.

@EricPostpischil You are very correct. Let me update that the assumption is no race conditions whatsoever.

@EricPostpischil if there are multiple processes operating on the same buffer, and the processes are scheduled preemptively, that the buffer won't be touched is not an assumption one should make - even without hardware registers being involved. The only person who can make that assumption is the person who chose to make it volatile in the first place. And even then, he runs the risk of shooting himself in the foot long after he forgets why this was done.

not after the call to the function

Synchronization and ordering are a separate question, not part of this question. To see that, consider that even if OP’s code operated on the data solely itself, reimplementing the library routine with volatile in its own code, there would still be problems if other processes were tinkering with the buffer while this process worked on it. It is something that needs to be dealt with in the application, but it is not part of the question being asked.

From C11 6.7.3 paragraph 7:

[…] If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.135)


135)This applies to those objects that behave as if they were defined with qualified types, even if they are never actually defined as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped input/output address).

OP's question is asking about the potential issues of removing the volatile qualifier when passing a pointer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type to a library function, i.e. when the type of the library function's formal parameter is not a pointer to a volatile-qualified type.
First, OP asks what could go wrong with the code. Using the parameter to refer to the volatile-qualified object results in undefined behavior, so anything could go wrong. I think it is OK if the function converts the parameter value to a pointer to a volatile-qualified type and only uses the converted pointer to access the object. There are no library functions in the C standard that are defined to behave like that.
Second, OP asks whether there is any way around it. The only way round it is to declare the object without a volatile-qualified type, and use some other mechanism to determine which parts of the object have a stable value at any given time and which parts have an unstable value. The stable part could be processed by a library function as long as the library function does not assume that it has any particular value, and as long as the function call is not optimized out.
One way to prevent a call to a library function being optimized out is to call it via a volatile function pointer. For example:
{
    void *(* volatile fp_memcpy)(void * restrict, const void * restrict, size_t) = memcpy;
    fp_memcpy(dest, src, n); // function call will not be optimized out
}

